# Compatibilté entre recommandation et contexte matériel

Tags: usage

La phrase suivante est correcte du point de vue syntaxe; la question est de savoir si les idées qui entrent dans sa construction sont compatibles; personnellement je ne le crois pas mais je n'ai pas accès à un avis d'expert qui pourrait confirmer cela. Y aurait-il quelqu'un qui puisse le confirmer, ou l'infirmer, et expliquer ses raisons ?

Mon point de vue est que lorsque la situation change soudainement, ce qui est une recommandation (1) à propos de quoi faire à ce moment précis (ayez un parapluie) n'est pas compatible avec l'ensemble des idées qui ont leur place dans ce contexte de changement; la recommandation (1) ne peut pas être conditionnelle à la réalisation du changement brusque. (« *Lorsque le temps tourne à la pluie, ouvrez un parapluie, si vous en avez un!* » ne contient plus ce défaut.)

> Lorsque le temps tourne à la pluie, ayez un parapluie.

(1) le terme utilisé initialement (prescription) était inexact et a été changé après lecture de la réponse de jlliagre.

Comment: J'avoue ne pas comprendre du tout où vous voulez en venir, malgré plusieurs relectures... Puis-je suggérer de clarifier ou reformuler  votre deuxième paragraphe ?

Comment: @Greg Tant pis, je ne trouve pas un meilleur moyen de l'exprimer; laissons passer.

Comment: @Greg Il veut simplement dire que le conseil (Ayez un parapluie) est difficilement applicable à un moment X (Lorsque le temps tourne à la pluie) sans un minimum de prévoyance. Un peu comme dire "Si vous avez un accident en vacances, prenez une assurance assistance". A vrai dire je pense que c'est la formulation "Si..." qui est un peu maladroite ici.

Comment: What seems weirdest to me is seeing “avoir” used in its imperative form to command (even suggest to) someone to “Have an umbrella!” without introducing/tempering it with something like “Soyez sûr d’avoir un/votre parapluie …” or “Il faut/vaut mieux avoir un/votre …”. I don’t think that adding any of those would alter (in either direction) the conditional nature of the command/suggestion, but their addition might make “have an umbrella” sound more like a recommendation and less like an attempt to state a truism or coin a proverb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien qu'on ne connaisse pas le contexte dans lequel elle est utilisée, la formule est un peu inattendue mais reste défendable.

D'une part, *le temps **tourne à la pluie*** ne décrit pas forcément un changement soudain comme présumé dans la question. Il se met rarement à pleuvoir sans que des signes avant-coureurs ne se manifestent. La personne peut donc avoir le temps de se munir d'un parapluie durant la période de transition vers le temps pluvieux.

D'autre part, ***ayez un parapluie*** peut se comprendre comme ***faites en sorte d'avoir un parapluie avec vous***. Une personne n'ayant pas anticipé le changement de temps peut là aussi disposer d'un peu de temps pour se conformer à la recommandation.

L'impératif *ayez* est rare. Quelques occurrences rencontrées dans la littérature montrent bien qu'il peut signifier : *prenez soin/faites en sorte d'avoir* :

> Mais, au théâtre, méfiez-vous, **ayez un talisman**, soyez sûr de prendre le public par des moyens connus; autrement, vous êtes un maladroit, et c'est bien fait si vous restez par terre. *Le naturalisme au théâtre : les théories et les exemples*, 1895, Émile Zola

J'aurais néanmoins plutôt tourné la phrase de la question comme ceci :

> Si le temps est pluvieux, n'oubliez pas de prendre un parapluie.

D'autres suggestions extraites des commentaires :

> Si le temps tourne à la pluie, soyez sûrs d'avoir un parapluie avec vous.
>
> Ayez un parapluie pour le cas où (il pleuvrait).

La logique de la dernière (un parapluie sert quand il pleut) m'inspire :

> Prenez un parapluie au cas où.

Comment: Donc, plutôt à éviter selon vous?

Comment: Plutôt à éviter, oui. Une autre suggestion : *veillez à prendre un parapluie avec vous*

Comment: « Si le temps tourne à la pluie, soyez sûrs d'avoir un parapluie avec vous » me semble aussi possible.

Comment: Et au fait, c'est pas vraiment une question de latitude. La pluie soudaine ça arrive fréquemment en altitude, quelle que soit la latitude.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'est vrai, et je me doutais que j'allais être repris sur ce point. D'un autre côté, je doute fort que le texte concerne un séjour en altitude car vu les risques de vent, y emporter un parapluie n'est probablement pas le meilleur conseil à donner...

Comment: Je pense qu'en retournant la phrase et en remplacant le "si" parce qu'il veut vraiment dire, "ayez" fonctionne un peu mieux, même si "prévoyez" ou "munissez-vous" sont quand-même moins directifs : "Ayez un parapluie pour le cas où (il pleuvrait)". Je mets "il pleuvrait" entre parenthèse car dans ce cas il est implicite, se protéger de la pluie étant le but premier du parapluie...